# How to assign values to new column in pandas df depending upon condition and values in other df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame:

```
recurring_credits = 
    narration   values   month_year
4   bupi upi    True    Sept-2019
5   bupi upi    False   Oct-2019
9   bupi upi    False   December-2019
11  merv visi   True    December-2019
12  neft pad    True    December-2019
17  bupi upi    False   December-2019
22  bupi upi    False   Oct-2019
27  bupi upi    False   December-2019
31  bupi upi    False   December-2019
32  bupi upi    True    Sept-2019
36  neft pad    True    Sept-2019
40  bupi upi    False   December-2019
44  bupi upi    False   December-2019
48  bupi upi    False   December-2019
49  bupi upi    False   December-2019
51  bupi upi    False   December-2019
53  imps bok    True    December-2019
58  imps bok    True    December-2019
60  bupi upi    False   December-2019
67  neft pad    True    January-2020
```

I have to create a column count number of transaction per month for unique narration and only true value otherwise zero.
My output df should be as below

```
df_out = 
    narration   values   month_year    tran/month
4   bupi upi    True    Sept-2019          2
5   bupi upi    False   Oct-2019           0
9   bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
11  merv visi   True    December-2019      1
12  neft pad    True    December-2019      1
17  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
22  bupi upi    False   Oct-2019           0
27  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
31  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
32  bupi upi    True    Sept-2019          2
36  neft pad    True    Sept-2019          1
40  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0 
44  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0  
48  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
49  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
51  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
53  imps bok    True    December-2019      2
58  imps bok    True    December-2019      2
60  bupi upi    False   December-2019      0
67  neft pad    True    January-2020       1
```

I have tried this but cannot get proper output:

```
unique_narration = list(recurring_credits['narration'].unique())
for narration in unique_narration:
    d = recurring_credits.loc[(recurring_credits['narration']==narration)&(recurring_credits['values']==True)]
    rec_pat = d.groupby('month_year', as_index=True).agg({'narration':'nunique'}).reset_index()
    rec_pat.columns = ['month_year','recurrance_number']
    recurring_credits['recurrance_pattern']=np.nan
    for i,j in zip(rec_pat.transaction_month_year,rec_pat.recurrance_number):
        recurring_credits['recurrance_pattern'].loc[(recurring_credits['narration']==narration)&(recurring_credits['month_year']==i)&(recurring_credits['values']==True)]=j
```

Comment: But what is your current output?

Comment: Why is `December-2019` `1` and `2` ?

Comment: Count of number of transactions for unique narration per month ie for neft pad there is only one transaction in December-2019 so 1 and for imps bok there is two transaction in December-2019 so it is 2 in the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break this into a couple of steps:

1. subset the dataframe where values == True
2. groupby("month_year") and get the counts of the unique "narration" values
3. take the above counts and merge it back to the original dataframe
4. fill NaNs from the merge with 0
5. Change dtype from float to int of our new column

#### Steps 1-2

```
usable_counts = (
    df.loc[df["values"]]
    .groupby(["month_year"])["narration"]
    .value_counts()
    .rename("tran/month")
)

print(usable_counts)
month_year     narration
December-2019  imps bok     2
               merv visi    1
               neft pad     1
January-2020   neft pad     1
Sept-2019      bupi upi     2
               neft pad     1
Name: tran/month, dtype: int64
```

#### Steps 3-5

Now that we have our counts per month_year/narration, we can merge it back to the original dataframe and clean up the end result:

```
final_df = (
    df.merge(
        usable_counts,
        left_on=["month_year", "narration"],
        right_index=True,
        how="left")
    .fillna(0)
    .astype({"tran/month": int})
)

print(final_df)
    narration  values     month_year  tran/month
4    bupi upi    True      Sept-2019           2
5    bupi upi   False       Oct-2019           0
9    bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
11  merv visi    True  December-2019           1
12   neft pad    True  December-2019           1
17   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
22   bupi upi   False       Oct-2019           0
27   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
31   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
32   bupi upi    True      Sept-2019           2
36   neft pad    True      Sept-2019           1
40   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
44   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
48   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
49   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
51   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
53   imps bok    True  December-2019           2
58   imps bok    True  December-2019           2
60   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
67   neft pad    True   January-2020           1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `narration` to `NaN` for `False` rows, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by number of unique values by [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for count non missing values:

```
s = (df.assign(new = df['narration'].where(df['values']))
       .groupby(['month_year','narration'])['new']
       .transform('count'))
df['tran/month'] = s
print (df)
    narration  values     month_year  tran/month
4    bupi upi    True      Sept-2019           2
5    bupi upi   False       Oct-2019           0
9    bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
11  merv visi    True  December-2019           1
12   neft pad    True  December-2019           1
17   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
22   bupi upi   False       Oct-2019           0
27   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
31   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
32   bupi upi    True      Sept-2019           2
36   neft pad    True      Sept-2019           1
40   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
44   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
48   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
49   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
51   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
53   imps bok    True  December-2019           2
58   imps bok    True  December-2019           2
60   bupi upi   False  December-2019           0
67   neft pad    True   January-2020           1
```

Comment: This is great but you are not taking into account narration.merv visi is having only one transaction in Dec 2019.

Comment: just playing around with answers: noticed that you don't need the temporary column `new`: `df.where(df["values"]).groupby(["month_year", "narration"])["narration"].transform("count")` seems to work for me

Comment: @CameronRiddell - hmm, tested, for me not.